# How exactly are Destructor calls made

Tags: constructor, operating-system, destructor

I wonder how exactly a constructor or destructor is being called for eg in c++? Im especially interested in the OS point of view. Im also interested in the case where we run android app written in java and we want to get info about user session. Can we use conatructor to set time of beginning of session and destr to set time of ending the session and save the data in database? Does actually OS handle destructors calls or something else? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of constructors you are asking about (At least I can remind two things could be called constructor in this context)? Also your question about set time is completely unclear.

Comment: @AlexHoppus I'm sorry for the unclearness in my question. The answer below completely covers my question, so I'll assume that deleting the unclear example about 'set time' will leave the topic clear and useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how Java handles constructor and destructor (Java involves virtual machine layer), but I'll try to answer this from a cpp point of view.

The short answer to your question: **OS does not participate in constructor or destructor (unless there's heap allocation, system call...). Compiler will insert calls to constructor and destructor in the right place when it generates machine code.**

For a simple program as follows:

```
class A{

    int* i;
public:
    A() { i = new int; }
    ~A() { delete i; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
}
```

Let's examine the assembly code emitted by compiler using `objdump`:

```
00000000004006a6 <main>:
  4006a6:       55                      push   %rbp
  4006a7:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4006aa:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  4006ae:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  4006b5:       00 00 
  4006b7:       48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  4006bb:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4006bd:       48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  4006c1:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4006c4:       e8 27 00 00 00          callq  4006f0 <_ZN1AC1Ev>
  4006c9:       48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  4006cd:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4006d0:       e8 3f 00 00 00          callq  400714 <_ZN1AD1Ev>
  4006d5:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4006da:       48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
  4006de:       64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
  4006e5:       00 00 
  4006e7:       74 05                   je     4006ee <main+0x48>
  4006e9:       e8 92 fe ff ff          callq  400580 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  4006ee:       c9                      leaveq 
  4006ef:       c3                      retq
```

Note that depending on the underlying architecture and compiler, your output might not be the same as mine, but the structure should generally be the same.

You can see compiler automatically generates calls to constructor `callq  400714 <_ZN1AD1Ev>` and destructor `callq  400714 <_ZN1AD1Ev>`. The assembly code for constructor is:

```
00000000004006f0 <_ZN1AC1Ev>:
  4006f0:       55                      push   %rbp
  4006f1:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4006f4:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  4006f8:       48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  4006fc:       bf 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%edi
  400701:       e8 8a fe ff ff          callq  400590 <_Znwm@plt>
  400706:       48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  400709:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  40070d:       48 89 10                mov    %rdx,(%rax)
  400710:       90                      nop
  400711:       c9                      leaveq 
  400712:       c3                      retq   
  400713:       90                      nop
```

Assembly for destructor:

```
0000000000400714 <_ZN1AD1Ev>:
  400714:       55                      push   %rbp
  400715:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400718:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40071c:       48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  400720:       48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400724:       48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  400727:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40072a:       e8 31 fe ff ff          callq  400560 <_ZdlPv@plt>
  40072f:       90                      nop
  400730:       c9                      leaveq 
  400731:       c3                      retq   
  400732:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400739:       00 00 00 
  40073c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Comment: This answer completely covers my question! Thank you!